# MercadoPago custom checkout throughs ""customer not found " error

Tags: javascript, mercadopago

I am working with mercadoPago Api of custom checkout. Firstly, i created a customer on mercado Api against my access token, then created a card token from the information user enter i.e card_number, security code etc, and finally i send a post request on mercadoPago payment Api by using customer email and card token but return error of "customer not found".

My request

```
{
        "transaction_amount": 100,
        "token": "2fe6477a6b238e2e90b055f5ad1f3735",
        "description": "Title of what you are paying for",
        "installments":1,
        "payment_method_id": "visa",
        "payer": {
            "email" : "test@test.com"
        }
```

}

and the response is

```
{
"message": "Customer not found",
"error": "bad_request",
"status": 400,
"cause": [
    {
        "code": 2002,
        "description": "Customer not found",
        "data": null
    }
]
```

}

the url is

https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments?access_token=my_access_token

Comment: Hi...Did you find any solution to this problem?? We are also facing the same.

Comment: No , I did't find any solution and finally move to mobile SDK.